# How do I continue my chapter/section numbering now my chapters are separate files?

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

I am using LaTeX to write my thesis. Originally, everything was in one .tex file. However, to help the compiling of some chapters, I have split each chapter into its own .tex file. Unfortunately, now my chapter and section numbering is completely wrong, as each chapter is now chapter 0 (the document is essentially one whole chapter), i.e the first subsection of the first chapter is 0.1, then the next starts as 0.4.

Here is my main .tex file,

```
%\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} % for one-sided printing
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book} % for two-sided printing


% List of packages to be used
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
%\usepackage[nosectionbib,numberedbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[square,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
%\citestyle{nature}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage{rotating}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'{e}}
%\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-initials}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usetikzlibrary{
   automata,
   positioning,
   backgrounds,
   shapes.arrows,
   decorations.pathreplacing,
   arrows,
   shapes.misc,
   decorations.markings,
   calc,
   patterns,
   angles,
   quotes,
   pgfplots.groupplots
}

%\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikzext/]

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ -- #1}{}}

\newcommand{\uchapter}[1]{%
 \chapter*{#1}%
 \markboth{#1}{}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{makecell} 
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}


% Title page information is here...% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

%% Front matter
%
% This is where we do the title page, etc.
%

\frontmatter

% Standard-Form Title Pages
\maketitle

% Abstract and Keywords
\uchapter{Abstract}
   Type your abstract here.  Type your abstract here.  Type your abstract here.  Type your abstract here.   Type your abstract here.
   \section*{Keywords}
   Keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3.

% Acknowledgements
\uchapter{Acknowledgements}
The author would like to thank \dots

Keith and Charlene
% Table of Contents
\sstableofcontents

% List of Figures
\sslistoffigures

% List of Tables
\sslistoftables

 
 % Dont forget to set spacing - If not implemented spacing will be double.
\setstretch{1.25}

\input{Chapters/1_Intro.tex}
\input{Chapters/2_Structure.tex}
\input{Chapters/3_Osteoarthritis.tex}
\input{Chapters/4_Physicochemistry.tex}
\input{Chapters/5_AnalyticalTechniques.tex}
\input{Chapters/6_Summary.tex}
\input{Chapters/7_MandM.tex}
\input{Chapters/8_Results.tex}
\input{Chapters/9_Discussion.tex}
\input{Chapters/10_Conclusion.tex}


\bibliography{references2}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

What am I missing or what should I edit to ensure the numbering is continued throughout the document?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Example chapter here:

```
\chapter{Summary of Literature, Aims and Objectives}

\subsection{Summary of Literature}
Summarise literature here

\subsection{Aims}

Insert aims here

\subsection{Objectives}

The following objectives were tested:

\begin{enumerate}
\item aim
\item aim
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Please note that we cannot test your code as we do not have any of the chapters. A sample chapter for one of them ought to be enough. Additionally, you're using `\frontmatter` where is `\mainmatter` in this example? Note that under a normal `\frontmatter` your `\uchapter` is irrelevant as that is the equivalent behaviour of `\chapter` under `\frontmatter`

Comment: I've just added an example chapter, I hope this helps. I used to have \mainmatter in my original .tex file just before the introduction chapter began, however it does not appear in my new .tex file.

Comment: Please note that your example without the chapters does not even compile. Fix the compilation problems first. What is `\sstableofcontents` and its friends?

Comment: After using `\tableofcontetns` instead and adding `\mainmatter` everything works as expected. Do note that `\section` should follow `\chapter` not `\subsection`

Comment: Thank you, the addition of \mainmatter has worked.

Comment: Next time please make sure the code you provide is self contained (aka does not try to access files others do not have access to) and make sure it compiles (unless that is the problem with the code). All of this saves updates a lot of time and it is easier to help.